# How to add a additional keyword in search?

Tags: php, search

```
<form action="search.php" method="post" class="search" id="search">
     <input name="search" id="search" type="text" value=""><br>
</form>
...
echo ".urlencode($_POST['search']).";
```

here is my basic search box. I want:
1. open the page first, the `".urlencode($_POST['search'])."` is empty.
2. when the client type some word and make a search, the `".urlencode($_POST['search'])."` will always add a additional keyword after client type word.

for example, when the client type: apple, the `".urlencode($_POST['search'])."` part show: `apple20%juice`, when the client type: orange, the ".urlencode($_POST['search'])." part show: `orange20%juice`, it always add a additional keyword `20%juice` behind the key word.

How to reach this one? Thanks.

Comment: You mean `%20`, not `20%`. This is the HTTP URL-encoded representation of a space character.

Comment: Anyway, I don't understand the problem. You haven't pointed out what's happening that's different from what you want to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this:

check if the search is set first if so go ahead and grab the string and add juice to it

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
  $searchterm = $_POST['search']." juice";
  //follw by other stmts...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply use;

```
print urlencode($_POST['search'].' juice');
```